Polylang & WP-All Import WooCommerce Plugin Compatibility
I'm trying to make WP All import WooCommerce add-on to work with Polylang and its WooCommerce add-on, but without any luck.
I came across this post here
WP All Import Pro: Polylang compatibility
But as far i can understand, what should happen, is to export all your current products with their IDs, map on Excel for example the exported IDs to the file with the second language, and import it as the second language to get the connection between the two products in their respective languages.
To be honest, having 20–30 products, it's ok to have it that way, but with 2000 or 3000 products, it's not going to work easy.
Did anyone had any luck with those 2 components ?
The way I see it, the only way to have this working correct, while importing the second language (the first language has the initial products) to have a function, before importing/updating a record, to search for the SKU (in my case that's the unique identifier of the product) and grap its ID, and add it to the solution Luca Reghellin suggested (link above) in the _import_translations_id custom field.
Does anyone have any idea on how to do that ?

I have been looking for weeks for a solution to use WP ALL IMPORT with Polylang Pro. The only plugin that works with wp all importy is WPML, but that makes the site so very slow, and is full of bugs, so I never want to use WPML again. I used other plugins to import products besides Wp all import, but they all fail in tiny aspects and small bugs compared to wp all import...
I hope there will be a solution, someday, ...
